# If a device's uncertainty for measuring time is $ 10^{-4} $, what happens to the uncertainty when the experimental value is squared?

Tags: kinematics, experimental-physics, time, error-analysis

**In a case where the device's uncertainty is found to be $ 10^{-4} $. As it is a device that measures a time interval; when squaring the experimentally obtained value, what should one do with the uncertainty?**

My initial thought is that I should use the following formula:

$$ \frac{\Delta t^{2}}{t^{2}} = 2 \frac{\Delta t}{t}  $$
where $\Delta t$ represents the uncertainty, $t$ the value obtained through the experiment.

Comment: Hi there and welcome on this stormy Sunday (i.e. here in Holland). Where did you get that last formula from? It looks like some kind of derivative. Shouldn't you use $t$ in de denominator?

Comment: See here: https://youtu.be/wx-fx60tHIU. Just change cm in sec. So the uncertainty is doubled. As I guess, your formula expresses.

Comment: Your formula is correct. Just use the general error propagation formula to derive it: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/529484/error-propagation-biot-savart-law/529728#529728

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct but a better way to represent it would be as follows-
$$y=x^n$$
Differentiating both sides we get
$$dy=nx^{n-1}\,dx$$
Dividing one with the other
$$\begin{align}
\frac {dy}y&=n\frac {x^{n-1}}{x^n}dx\\
\frac {dy}y&=n\frac {dx}{x}\\
\end{align}$$
Hence, the power is multiplied with the error when dealing with exponents. However as derivation was calculated with calculus, the $dx$ component here is infinitesimally small. As long as the error is really small compared to the absolute value $(dx\approx \Delta x\lll x)$, the approximation will be reasonably accurate. But as the value of $\Delta x$ gets larger, the error will become greater than the calculated value.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I'm not that skillful in  calculus, so I took this forumula for granted in my highschool course. However, would you mind justifying it a bit further, at least when it comes to the limitations of it.